# Python - Keeping text file in one line?

Tags: python, lines

I'm making a code that shows a product list in an ordered way, and the user can input a GTIN-8 code and select an amount they wish to 'purchase'. So when the user inputs a GTIN-8 code, FullLine should be the product description etc which is in the product list and show the amount. However, the amount is appearing on a new line which I don't want. I've tried putting the newline after the product list, before it and under it, but it won't stay on the same line.
Here is the code:

```
nl="\n"
Products=open("Productsfile.txt","w")
Products.write(nl+"23456945, Thorntons Chocolate Box, £10.00")
Products.write(nl+"12376988, Cadburys Easter Egg, £15.00")
Products.write(nl+"76543111, Galaxy Bar, £1.00")
Products.write(nl+"92674769, Cadury Oreo Bar, £1.00")
Products.write(nl+"43125999, Thorntons Continental Box, £12.00")
Products.close()

Products=open("Productsfile.txt","r")
print(Products.read())

Receipt=open("ReceiptFile.txt","w")
Receipt.write("Here are your purchases: \n")
Receipt.close()

print("Please enter the GTIN-8 Codes of the products you want and how many")
IfFinished=""
while IfFinished != "Yes":
    ProductsWanted=input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product: ")
    AmountOfProducts=input("How many do you want? ")

    with open("Productsfile.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
                if ProductsWanted in line:
                    FullLine=(line +"Amount: " +AmountOfProducts)
                    print(FullLine)
                    Receipt=open("ReceiptFile.txt","a")
                    Receipt.write(str(FullLine))
                    Receipt.close()
```

So when running, I get, e.g.:

```
23456945, Thorntons Chocolate Box, £10.00
Amount: 2
```

However I want the Amount on the same line

Comment: Try using `line.strip()` to return a new string without any leading or trailing whitespace, including the newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Using rstrip method, Change the `FullLine=(line +"Amount: " +AmountOfProducts)`

to `FullLine=(line.rstrip() +"Amount: " +AmountOfProducts)`

Comment: Hi @Chloe if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.